# web app - static website which updates the text file

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, static

I was creating a **simple grocery list website** using CSS, JS, HTML so that I and my friends can use it. I will be hosting it to GitHub for free. The problem with GitHub is that it can only host static websites. So if I update my list it only updates in my device and not in my friend's device.

I have seen some tutorials online, they use servers, database and dynamic content. So my question is, is there any way possible like **saving the list into a text file in Github** repository without using a dynamic site.
And from this text file, JS can fetch the list again whenever I update, delete, refresh the page. Or doing this will make it a dynamic website?

**I want to have a static website and update the grocery list for all the people who visit the site.**

Thank you for your answer. I am new to HTML, CSS, JS and I know I am missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any good solutions involving Github, but I think you'd be better off using something like [Firebase Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart). It's basically a nosql (JSON-like) database which you can access directly from your client (javascript). Also you get 1 GiB of free data which will be more than enough for your use case. They provide an easy to use interface so you can save and fetch your data super quickly, it's a bit like saving JSON in the cloud. Hope this helps solve your issue.

Comment: I checked out the Firebase. It can be used and very easy to learn indeed. I will try to learn this technology. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So you could use the browser stored cache file which is a JSON file to do this (it would be great practice for you as well) - keep in mind the flow of information would only be one way i.e. you're going to update the JSON file in chrome, they will download this and that will be passing the data) -

The document that you are going to want to look at is this one on the local storage of a browser:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

I hope this helps

thx - W

Comment: Does this mean only I can update the JSON file and they can only access it? I want to have all the people able to update the list. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: if they are tech savy people who can push a request to github to update the JSON file then they could do that (but honestly I think that will be a night mare, as you'd need to track all the updates and who's was most up to-date) - 

An alternative to this (hacky) is to use googleSheets and make the list public then use a fetch request (which is a built in JS web API function) to populate the data.

But try to keep in mind with this - that it is for these reasons that people created data-bases, it might be time to learn how to use them and NODE.JS / EXPRESS to handle this

Comment: It is perfectly fine to use data-bases. I just wanted to use a static site for this since hosting is free on Github. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: if this was the answer that you where looking for, could you mark the post as answered. Thanks and hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

Usually, just as you must have guessed by now, GitHub is perfect for static pages, and if you must make a dynamic page you will have to spin up a server and a database probably.

Nevertheless, there are several ways you can solve this, first, you can host a JSON file somewhere on a free server like http://000webhost.com and then use javascript to fetch the JSON file and dump something on screen-based off that data. This, of course, you will notice will take extra work creating a simple API that will store your groceries data somewhere else. If you don't want to use 000webhost there are other options, just use the keyword "free hosting" you will see a lot of options to choose from on google.

Another way is to use Web Storage, I'm talking about creating a javascript JSON like object as your data and store it in local storage, totally depending on how much you will scale in the future, you might risk filling up your browser storage disk, there is just how far it can take right. Then you can simply fetch from the storage with JS and display on-screen likewise.

Another way is to entirely go static by manually hard coding everything inside your codebase.

In conclusion, speaking of static site generators, there are a lot of other alternatives that might just surprise you, check this one out I use to quickly show a prototype for a static page. - https://surge.sh

I hope this gives you an idea of what to do now?
Explore!